# Evaluation of MongoDB expressions stored into document fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I would like to filter the documents in collection testData based on the satisfaction of a boolean expression specified within the field cd of each document (each document of the collection can have a different condition and set of fields)

Let us suppose that the expression is

```
var exp={$gte: [x, 5]}
```

to set the value of cd within a document I have invoked `JSON.stringify(exp)`

My documents are similar to this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("543650b5433d4688a9a029ee"), "x" : 28, "cd" : "{\"$gte\":[\"x\",\"5\"]}" }
```

I would like to specify an aggregate query where each document is processed / pruned out based on the value of cd.

I tried to specify a query like this:

```
db.testData.aggregate([
{ 
    $redact:
    {
        $cond: {
            if: cd,
            then: '$$KEEP',
            else: '$$PRUNE'
        }
    }
}
])
```

But i get this error:

> Error: cannot convert native function to BSON at src/mongo/shell/query.js:81

I have also tried referring to the field path of cd with `$` in this way:

```
db.testData.aggregate([
{ $redact:
    {
        $cond: {
            if: '$cd',
            then: '$$KEEP',
            else: '$$PRUNE'
        }
    }
}
])
```

but in this case all documents that includes cd are selected, independently on cd value.

I'm wondering what should I do to force the evaluation of the condition cd.

Comment: You can't do that. Why don't you just simply store "cd" as 5 ?

Comment: You cannot evaluate a string. This is not JavaScript invoking an `eval()` method, the operators are all placed in C++ code which is natively compiled. Bottom line is that you cannot place "expressions as strings" in your data as you have. But if you take the time to edit your question and explain your real purpose, then there might just be an answer.